Bad sectors on HDD in RAID10 array, how to replace it?
My first post here and i want to say hello. Hope this is right place to ask.
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server with 4x 20TB as a storage in RAID10 array (created by mdadm) with XFS filesystem. Every disk is TOSHIBA MG10ACA20TE. Yesterday I recevied this mail:
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  ubuntu
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], ATA error count increased from 2 to 3

Device info:
TOSHIBA MG10ACA20TE, S/N:XXXXXXXXX, WWN:XXX, FW:0102, 20.0 TB

I checked SMART results and it showed reallocated_sector_ct=59:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       9508
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       59
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       10476
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
 23 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 24 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 27 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       787503
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2206
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48 (Min/Max 20/60)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       23
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       524288
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   076   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       9861
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       688
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       87461071488
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       671368578512

Now my question is, what should I do in this situation? I know I must replace this disk ASAP, but how should I do it without destroying anything and not losing my data? I saw some tutorials for RAID1 where they wrote to create the same partitions on the new drive, then mark the faulty drive as failed and remove it from the RAID, then add the new drive and wait for the RAID to synchronize. But does this apply to RAID10? Is this the way I should do it? I already have the same drive for replacement, the data is sent via rsync to an identical server in another location.
I hope someone would help me. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Welcome to AskUbuntu!
With RAID10, a lot of the stress of replacing a failed drive is gone because you already have an exact copy of everything you need to rebuild the array.
For this answer I'm going to make the following assumptions:

There is only one failed drive, /dev/sdd
The RAID10 array uses the following devices:

/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde


The RAID array is defined in the same order as the storage devices:

0 ⇢ sdb + sdc
1 ⇢ sdd + sde


Each storage device has a single data partition

Be sure to adjust these for your actual system configuration if required.
With this said, if /dev/sdd is the one that's failing, you have everything you need on /dev/sdb. However, before we continue ...
Important
Because you will be performing I/O intensive operations, it is strongly recommended that all server operations on this machine be disabled. This includes file sharing, database operations, and anything that might require reading or writing to the array. If the server is being used by a business during business hours, carve out a maintenance window where everybody understands that the server will not be accessible. Failing to do this can result in less-than-enjoyable consequences.
With that out of the way, let's get started. Here are the steps you'll need to follow:

SSH in to the server or log in on the physical machine itself

Mark the bad device as failed, and remove it from the array:
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sdd1
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --remove /dev/sdd1


Remove the failed storage device from the kernel:
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdd/device/delete


Remove the failed storage device from the server. If the device is not in a hot-swappable bay, this means shutting the server off and replacing the bad device with the new one. Once the server is ready to continue, move on to step 5.

Write partition table to the new device using sfdisk, copying the partition data from sdb to the new sdd:
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdd

Note: Do not make a mistake here. It will ruin your day. Make absolutely certain that the first sfdisk command is reading from a good device, and the second is the new device. When using sudo, Linux will not ask "Are you sure?" before carrying out instructions.

Verify that the new storage device matches the old storage device. The partition output of the following commands should be the same:
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd

Which will give you something like:
Device         Start         End    Sectors     Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  2872214527 2872212480 18415.9G Linux filesystem

...

Device         Start         End    Sectors     Size Type
/dev/sdd1       2048  2872214527 2872212480 18415.9G Linux filesystem


Set a random device GUID to reduce conflicts with other devices:
sgdisk -G /dev/sdd


Add the new device to the array:
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdd1

Note: Be sure to change /dev/md2 if your array is named something different.
At this point the server will begin the process of filling the new storage device with data. Depending on how much you have and the limitations of the hardware, this could take a while. You can always check on the status of the resync with the following command:
cat /proc/mdstat



That's pretty much all there is to it. These steps might look daunting if you've never replaced a bad storage device before, but the modern tools have come a long way to reduce as much friction and stress as possible.
One final note, if you have smartmontools running, it will continue to complain about /dev/sdd as being a failed drive. You will need to reset it with the following command:
sudo service smartd restart

Once the resync is complete, do not forget to restart the file shares and any databases that may read from the array.

I forget to mention. Whole array is encrypted with LUKS2. I created the array in cockpit: selected 4 disks, choose RAID type, named it and whole array was created. After entering the array, I clicked format partition, gave a name, a mount point, file system and then selected encryption with LUKS2. Does this make any difference when replacing the drive? I did a VM to reconstruct my problem and did everything what you wrote and there was no problem. I just want to be sure before I gonna touch anything on production server. And thank you so much for your help.
